# Local dev issue with transform and detect plugin

Tags: image-transforms

I have a local, staging and production setup (Craft 2.6.3011).
My local site is having a problem with transforms that seems to be related to the mobile detect plugin (I am using Mikkel Rummelhoff's [Detect Plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/Detect-Craft)).

The Detect code I'm using in my template is: `{% set isMobile = craft.detect.isMobile ? '1' : '0' %}`

The home page has four images that 404 with transform urls.
If I look at the response I see the following errors:

```
Twig_Error_Runtime
Neither the property "detect" nor one of the methods "detect()", "getdetect()"/"isdetect()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Craft\CraftVariable" in "_includes/header.html" at line 102. (/mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:660)

#0 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(64): Twig_Template->getAttribute(Object(Craft\CraftVariable), 'detect', Array, 'any', false, false)
#1 /mylocaldevpath/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/f6/f671e04469d81f0dfda61111136d722fb954e341b7543ce8baa919e43343b4ae.php(244): Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute(Object(Craft\CraftVariable), 'detect', Array)
#2 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_81873f0b87bd6a678f4bf938ed6516d87c5b9a4339fc9d6dfcf337b2f069a6f9->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#3 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#4 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#5 /mylocaldevpath/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/12/129e9e7cc1b6a86df018442a329dd1d6e1f7d9c31cb94b7b01ae6cfeff6f2ebd.php(198): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#6 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_11ee36b35600746e068e6dd5ace4c2797e2ec35ca7d474eb36bb37f7250bd707->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#7 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#8 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#9 /mylocaldevpath/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/fe/fe5ea1b61c6d52fa030f7f1d75b2b4568bab6dfe912af74613b657eed595f6fe.php(43): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#10 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_455d61df868203e0a6669f803e3d1b9e9a10f94ed6abe1e14ec8e1bee9d1c1e1->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#11 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#12 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#13 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(411): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#14 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(363): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#15 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(256): Twig_Environment->render('404', Array)
#16 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('404', Array)
#17 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php(213): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('404', Array)
#18 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\TemplatesController->actionRenderError()
#19 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#20 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#21 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#22 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('renderError')
#23 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(368): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#24 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php(281): CErrorHandler->renderError()
#25 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(351): Craft\ErrorHandler->renderError()
#26 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(218): CErrorHandler->renderException()
#27 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php(145): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#28 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(131): Craft\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#29 /mylocaldevpath/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(750): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#30 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#31 {main}
```

If I remove the plugin code from my template and rename the 'detect' plugin folder then I just get the 404s with no useful response. I have checked permissions for assets (macOS - MAMP Pro) and these seem fine. I can see the source images for the transforms but it always 404s the transform url.
This is a multilingual site in 9 languages and works 100% perfect apart from this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and include the snippet of Twig code that you're using to do the "detecting"? Looks like it's in `_includes/header.html`...

Comment: Did you install the plugin on all your environments? Because it says it could not find the plugin. And of course as already said we need your code

Comment: Sites been deployed for over a year. Staging is working fine.
It's just locally that i see this problem. Plugin is there and exists.
Updated question with plugin code

Answer (score 1):

Such a klutz: My local basePath was incorrect.
Detect plugin was a red-herring.

All solved